# Camera images being saved to sdcard as empty files?

Tags: android, camera

I was wondering if any1 could tell me why my photos are being saved with a size of 0kb meaning that they are empty?... i checked my sd card and they are being saved but with nothing in them... heres the code

```
public class CameraAPI extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

public Camera camera;
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
CBDataBaseHelper RH;
TextView RecipeID;
Bitmap finalBitmap;

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    boolean diditwork;
    try{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    RecipeID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rid2);
    String RowID;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();    
    RowID = extras.getString("SELECTED2");
    RecipeID.setText(RowID);
    SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.acccam);
    SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}catch(Exception e){
    diditwork = false;
    String error = e.toString();
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("darn");
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(error);
    d.setContentView(tv);
    d.show();
}}

        public void takePhoto(View view){
            //String ID = RecipeID.getText().toString();
            //Long LID = Long.parseLong(ID);
            boolean diditwork;
            try{
            takePicture();
            }catch(Exception e){
                diditwork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("darn");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
            //String path = "/sdcard/Image.jpg";
            //RH.updateRecipe3(LID,path);

    }




public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mediaRecorder == null){
        try{
            camera = camera.open();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();

        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}



public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}

public void takePicture(){
boolean diditwork;
    try{
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }catch(Exception e){
        diditwork = false;
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("darn");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    }
}


ShutterCallback shutterCallback= new ShutterCallback()
{
    public void onShutter(){

    }
};

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){

        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback(){
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
        //  FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            boolean diditwork;
            File myDir=new File("/sdcard");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "/Image"+ n +".jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname);


            if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
            try {

                   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                   out.flush();
                   out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
                RH = new CBDataBaseHelper(CameraAPI.this);

                RH.open();
                String ID = RecipeID.getText().toString();
                Long RID = Long.parseLong(ID);
                RH.updateRecipe3(RID, myDir +fname);
                RH.close();
            //String ID = RecipeID.getText().toString();
            //Long RID = Long.parseLong(ID);
            //RH.updateRecipe3(RID, myDir + fname);

        }







};
}
```

thanks Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

finalBitmap is never initialized, so I'd assume that you're catching a Null Pointer Error every time in the try catch block in the jpegCallback. You also aren't doing anything with the byte array passed to you in the callback, which means you aren't doing anything to save the image. Try doing the following in the beginning of onPictureTaken in jpegCallback:

```
finalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

see [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) for more info

If your goal is to simply allow a user to take a picture and you don't care much about the details, by far the easiest thing to do is to use startActivityForResult and let the native camera app handle taking the picture and creating the file. If you need to use the image created afterward, you can pass in a Uri so that you know where the image will be saved. This has the added bonus of working with Android's MediaStore.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
//Uri is parcelable so you can save this to a bundle in onSaveInstanceState
//and retrieve it in onResume
photoUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new    ContentValues());
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
// Lanuch the activity
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
```

You can then handle the result by implement onActivityResult(). See [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)